# Steps to investigate battery drain issue on Android

Tags: android, battery

I am working on an Android app now and now it is in beta release. However, a number of my beta users are claiming that they are experiencing battery drain, compared to before installing the app.

It looks like it is only impacting some users, but I am unable to pinpoint why yet.

I am using GPS and GCM in this application. I have followed the guidelines in Android Developers' documentation (removing the location client when onStop() is called). The app will not attempt to refresh data from the server if there is no network connection. However, I have some users saying that the app is in background all the time but the app drained more than 10% of the battery. (!!)

1) Should I remove the WAKE_LOCK permission associated with GCM?

2) What else can I do about the get Location? I am only calling getLocation in a few activities when they start. There is no interval update.

3) Any other potential battery drain culprits that I may missed out?

Comment: This is far too broad without know the details of the application. You could look into optimising your code, but I'd be inclined to install a battery monitoring application and see if you can pin point it. Google location services were brutal on the battery around JellyBean stage, and only with Kitkat and options like "low power" mode for location has this began to improve. It could depend on the device they are using, coverage, network location mode etc, and just human expectation. Some people freak out at losing 1% of their battery. There's no way to answer this really.

Comment: First, check if the users are right. Second, check a battery monitor app. You could also try to test each component seperately and see how they do (eg location determination without all the other stuff like UI and calculations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have determined that the issue is linked to Wake Lock used in GCM implementation.

It looks like after the device is woken up after receiving a push notification, it is not going back to sleep properly.

Thanks for the responses. I am posting this and hope this help anyone who may have the same issue.